# Difference quotient for solutions of ODE and Liouville equation

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Suppose that $\Phi$ is the solution of 
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(x,t) = f(\Phi(x,t),t) \quad t >0 \\
\Phi(x,0) = x \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^N
\end{cases}$$

> How does one prove that 
>    $$\tilde \Phi(x,y,t) = \left(\Phi(x,t), \frac{\Phi(x + r y,t) - \Phi(x,t)}{r} \right)$$
>   is the flow of the ODE with 
>   $$\tilde{f}_r(x,y,t) = \left(f(x,t), \frac{f(x+r y,t) - f(x,t)}{r}  \right)$$
>   as a vector field?

Also, in an answer to [Prove that the flow of a divergence-free vector field is measure preserving](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327781/prove-that-the-flow-of-a-divergence-free-vector-field-is-measure-preserving), it was proved that if $\mu_t = (\Phi(\cdot,t))_{\sharp} \mu$ denote the image of the measure $\mu$ by the flow of $f$, then the family of measures $\{\mu_t\}_{t\in \mathbb R}$ satisfies Liouville equation 
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t \mu_t + \operatorname{div\,} (f \mu_t) = 0 \\
\mu_0 = \mu
\end{cases}
$$
in the sense of distributions.

> What PDE does $\tilde\mu_t = (\tilde\Phi_t)_{\sharp}  \mu$ solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Question 1:* Denoting   $U:= \Phi(x,t)$ and $\displaystyle V:={\Phi(x + r y,t) - \Phi(x,t)\over r}$  the components of $\tilde \Phi(x,y,t)$  , we have  $U+rV=\Phi(x + r y,t) $,  and $$\displaystyle\frac{f(U+r V,t) - f(U,t)}{r} = \frac{f(\Phi(x + r y,t),t) - f(\Phi(x,t),t)}{r} .$$ 
So

$$\partial_t\tilde \Phi(x,y,t)= $$$$= \left(\partial_t \Phi(x,t) , \frac{\partial_t\Phi(x + r y,t)  - \partial_t\Phi(x,t) }{r} \right)$$
$$= \left(f(\Phi(x,t),t), \frac{f(\Phi(x + r y,t),t) - f(\Phi(x,t),t)}{r} \right)$$
$$= \left(f(U,t), \frac{f(U+r V,t) - f(U,t)}{r}  \right)$$$$=\tilde{f}_r(U,V,t)   $$
$$=\tilde{f}_r(\tilde \Phi(x,y,t),t).$$

*Question 2:*  as to $\tilde\mu_t$, the same result of the quoted link apply *in particular* to  the flow $\tilde\Phi$, therefore you still have the Liouville equation $\partial_t {\tilde\mu}_t + \operatorname{div\,} ({\tilde f}  {\tilde\mu_t) }= 0$

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "conjugation" in this context?

Comment: You're welcome. Is the answer clear to you? As to question 2, the evolution of $\tilde\mu_t$  is a *particular case* of the result for $\mu_t$. (As to the conjugation: it was not important, and didn't make  it any clearer, I removed).

Comment: Thank you. The answer to question 1 is clear. About question 2, I'm not quite sure about what the divergence in  $\partial_t {\tilde\mu}_t + \operatorname{div\,} ({\tilde f}  {\tilde\mu_t) }= 0$ really is. Could you write it out in terms of $f$ instead of $\tilde f$, please?

Comment: Also, can this be made rigorous even when $f$ is a Sobolev or BV function?

Comment: @PietroMajer I deleted my answer to the Borsuk problem. I wrote it without thinking much (rushing to a lecture). As a result your comment has been deleted so you should post it as a comment to the question or as an answer.

Comment: @PietroMajer I've asked my follow-up question as a separate post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328535/difference-quotients-of-solutions-of-ode-and-pde-in-sobolev-setting